# How to give vscode permission to mkdir without using it as sudo su, I'm using mint 20

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I recently installed mint and I'm doing some tests on VSCode, I'm a long time windows user but I ran into a problem. I program nodejs and when I run npm install, it gives permission access errors and I want to know if there's a way around it that isn't running vscode as super user.
Error:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/dotta/Documents/Udemy Codes/surf_shop/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /home/dotta/Documents/Udemy Codes/surf_shop/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/dotta/Documents/Udemy Codes/surf_shop/node_modules'
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following

`ls -la /home/dotta/Documents/Udemy\ Codes/surf_shop` you will see that its owned by `root`, why because you run `sudo npm install` at some point.

To fix:

1. Delete node_modules:

`sudo rm -rf /home/dotta/Documents/Udemy\ Codes/surf_shop/node_modules`

2. Then fix ownership permissions:

`sudo chown dotta:dotta -R /home/dotta/Documents/Udemy\ Codes`

Then you will be able to `npm install`, don't use sudo to install or make directories else when you want to do stuff as a normal user you wont own the directory or file.

Also dont start vs-code as root i.e: `sudo code .` else any point within vs-code its making folders/files as root.

...
sidenote, avoid spaces in folders or filenames.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give VSCODE admin right,go to VSCODE icon click right button -> properties -> advanced -> grant admin right and close all old terminals on VSCODE ,open a new one and enjoy !